# Using libcurl on windows, in my c++ project, with visual studio, does not work because string get corrupted

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, curl, libcurl

As explained in the title, I am trying to use the libcurl C API to submit simple http query.

I am using windows as an OS, C++ as a language, Visual Studio 2008 as an IDE.

My code is quiet simple:

I initialize curl:
`CURLcode init = curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);`

I initialize my handle: 
`CURL* handle = curl_easy_init();`

I set the url:
`CRULcode set_url = curl_easy_setopt(handle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.example.com")`

I submit my request: `CURLcode submit = curl_easy_perform(handle);`

As a result, the `init`  and `set_url` return codes are 0 (`CURLE_OK`), the subimt return code is 2 (`CURLE_URL_MALFORMAT`).

When I debug I realize that my URL got corrupted, and instead of being http://www.example.com it becomes: `xj:` in release mode and `0|:` in debug mode.
It happens as soon as I enter `curl_easy_setopt`

The URL string gets definitely corrupted.

There must be one of my settings that is wrong, so here is a summary of my settings (in debug mode)

- Use MFC in a Shared DLL
- Use Multi-Byte Character Set
- preprocessor includes CURL_STATICLIB
- Multi-threaded Debug DLL /MDd
- Linking againgst libcurld.lib (version 7.21.3) compile using the vc6curl.dsw project
- also linking againgst ws2_32.lib wldap32.lib

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Linking againgst libcurld.lib (version 7.21.3) compile **using the vc6curl.dsw project**"

This is the problem.

Static libraries must be built with the same compiler and the same runtime libraries (/MDd).

You can avoid this with DLL version of libcurl.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The simple code I've written works. Nevertheless, I still have two issues. The first one is if I call `curl_easy_getinfo` on the effective URL, I still get the same junk as before. Also When I try to do something more complicated (setting the URL and performing the query from somewhere else), I get an error when setting the url. In debug it crashes in dbgheap.c, and in release it just crashes, complaining about heap corruption.

Comment: @junes those problems could happen if you link libcurld.lib(debug) with release build or vise versa. Static library link is somewhat tricky. As said before, you must match compiler / compiler version / compile options / runtime library version / runtime library type.

Comment: But now I am using the dll, and in my linker input I use libcurl_imp.lib and libcurld_imp.lib (in debug). I find it somehow very difficult to use libcurl on windows with visual studio...

Comment: @jules First, `curl_easy_getinfo` can be used only AFTER the connection made and transfer begin. libcurl doesn't copy input url before it perform so set url here call perform there could cause bad memory reference. You could make a static variable that hold the url string and setinfo url using the static variable.

Comment: ok, I understand. The issue was that my URL was stored in the stack and went out of scope before I performed the query. It's a bit of a burden to have to store the URL until the query get performed. Thanks for your help.